# Google Analytics API custom dashboard - Page of active users

Tags: charts, google-analytics, google-api, analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm new with the Google Anapytics API to make a custom dashboard on my personal website. I've done almost the charts, but I also need to get the "Active Screen Name" under Real-Time counter:

[image: my website]

The voice on GA is the following:

[image: google-analytics]

Is it possible? How? I'm searching over the net but i didn't found anything about...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you have to use the [Real Time Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/) for this data, which is in beta. The call would look something similar to:

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/realtime?ids={VIEW_ID}&metrics=rt%3ApagePath&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

[Here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/dimsmets/pagetracking) are the Real-Time Page Tracking metrics for reference.

Comment: Works! Thank you :)